# Create pattern rule for patterns in a variable?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have this simple pattern rule

```
%.o : %.cpp
    recipe
```

I'd like to use this rule but with the added constraint that the pattern matches one of the words in a variable called FILENAMES.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as [Static Pattern Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern).

With that syntax you provide list of possible targets, but use pattern for generate own rule for every target in this list:

```
FILENAMES = foo bar
# Generate list of precise targets names
FILENAMES_OBJ = $(addsuffix .o, $(FILENAMES))

$(FILENAMES_OBJ): %.o: %.cpp
    <recipe>
```